# 'this' within anonymous class

Tags: android, class, this, anonymous

I noticed weird thing.In the anonymous class this reference points to outer class.For instance:

```
public MyView view;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toggleFullscreen(true);
    this.view=new MyView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //load data
    LoadGameDataTask task=new LoadGameDataTask(..loading params);

    task.setListener(new LoadGameDataTask.OnDataLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnDataLoaded(GameData data) {
    //this -reference to activity
            Log.d("load","completed,this:"+this.toString());// D/load: completed,this:net.rhyboo.com.gl_test.MainActivity$1@34dfbb38
            //this.setContentView(this.view);
        }
    });
    task.execute();
}
```

If I run this code - I can see `this` points to my activity after data loading completed.However if I uncomment `this.setContentView(this.view);` - I got compile error - `cannot resolve method setContentView`. Its because compiler thinks that `this` is reference to `LoadGameDataTask.OnDataLoadedListener`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I would advise against calling `setContentView` after the loading of the first view. If you want to show different layouts, Fragments are recommended

Comment: Its for testing purposes only, of course in production I will clean up this crap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous classes have automatic names assigned - a `$` is prepended with a sequence number to the outer class name.
`net.rhyboo.com.gl_test.MainActivity$1`. Notice this is not the MainActivity class, but the anonymous class name. `$1` means the first inner class.

To access the outer class from an anonymous inner class you should add the name of the outer class. If your activity is `MainActivity` then use:

`MainActivity.this.setContentView(this.view);`

Comment: Indeed it works with MainActivity.this.Thanks.Is 'this' property specific for activity class?Or I can access outer scope in any place?

Comment: `this` always points to the current class. If you are inside the anonymous inner class then the current class is the anonymous inner class. When you are inside an inner class, there is an outer scope also. To access the outer scope you write the outer class name before `this` => `MainActivity.this`

Comment: yeah I got it.Can I do the same trick with my custom class?Like
public class OuterClass {

Comment: damn pressed enter accidentaly.I mean if anonimous class will be in my class(not activity) Can I access outer class with the same trick?

Comment: Well, an activity is just a class, nothing special. So you can do the same and access the outer class :)

Comment: its true.There is static `this` property for any class

Comment: thanks guys.Some extra symbols to make comment longer

Comment: You are welcome :) If you think my answer was helpful and solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking on the green tick mark next to the upvotes number. It is how StackOverflow works basically.

Comment: I'm trying but it says I have to have at least 15 reputation.

Comment: Ah, ok. I forgot that :)

Comment: Damn. Forgot to accept the answer. Sorry for a delay :)